# Move "My billing and shipping address are the same" to shipping section

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.2, payment, shipping-address, billing-address

I am developing a shopping site. In the one page checkout, the "My billing and shipping address are the same" section is in the payment method. I want it to be below the Billing address. The payment method will stay at its own place. I just want to move the checkbox with the address to billing method section.
How can I achieve this?
thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the fastest way to reach it is:

1. Create the file similar like `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state.js` where you will be store a state of checkbox
2. In the `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js` instead the variable "`isAddressSameAsShipping`" use a value created in the step 1st. (you can check how it's done for "form-popup-state")
3. Move checkbox with label from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address.html` into `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` file
4. Create in the `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js` method to change state a value from step 1st by checkbox from step 3rd.

Of course you should override all files in your extension or theme, not in the vendor :)

Comment: Hi, I tried this but didnot work. Could you please be a bit more elaborate. Thank you

Comment: So please what is your problem?